# how do I pass in a custom validate message in react hook form?

Tags: react-hook-form

```
  <input name="request.url" placeholder="URL" ref={register({
    required: true,
    validate: validURL
  })} />
```

validURL is a function, but how do I display a custom message here?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Pass your custom validate message directly to the rule, example:

```
<input name="request.url" placeholder="URL" ref={register({
    required: "The field is required",
    validate: validURL // Should return true or a string if not ok
  })} />
```

Here is the doc: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

[image]

Comment: For those wanting to see an example... assuming `validURL` returns `true/false`, you can do `validate: validURL || "That URL is not valid!"` to return a custom message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return custom message with validate function use ||

```
<input name="request.url" placeholder="URL" ref={register({
    required: "The field is required",
    validate: (value)=> your validation || your custom message
  })} />
```