React-hook-form: Add custom error messages for validation functions?
With react-hook-form, you can add a custom error message for required like this:
    rules={{
      required: "This field is required",

How do you add custom error messages for multiple validate functions provided as an object?
      validate: {
        noEmoji: validateNoEmoji,
        noNumbersNoPunctuation: validateOnlyLettersSpacesApostrophes,
      },

For example, I want to add a message "You can't use emoji" for noEmoji and "You cannot use numbers or punctuation." for noNumbersNoPunctuation.
This is my controller:
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    rules={{
      required: "This field is required",
      validate: {
        noEmoji: validateNoEmoji,
        noNumbersNoPunctuation: validateOnlyLettersSpacesApostrophes,
      },
    }}
    render={({
      field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
    }) => (
      <IonInput
        label={label}
        name={name}
        value={value}
      />
    )}
  />

And here are the validation functions:
const validateNoEmoji = (value: string) => !/[\uD798-\uDFFF]/.test(value);

const validateOnlyLettersSpacesApostrophes = (value: string): boolean => {
  // Allow only letters and whitespace and apostrophes.
  if (!/[^a-zA-Z ']/.test(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};


Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927236/how-do-i-pass-in-a-custom-validate-message-in-react-hook-form

@HarshaLimaye Thank you, but I think my question is different because I am passing an object of functions, unless I'm missing something.

Just return error message when your validation function failed.
Check the doc: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register
const validateNoEmoji = (value: string) => 
    !/[\uD798-\uDFFF]/.test(value) ? true :  "You can't use emoji";

const validateOnlyLettersSpacesApostrophes = (value: string): boolean => {
  // Allow only letters and whitespace and apostrophes.
  if (!/[^a-zA-Z ']/.test(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  return "You cannot use numbers or punctuation.";
};

